# Error Code: 1215 in mysql cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an issue and I feel like I fixed everything. MySQL workbench is still giving me this error. If you can please explain what is wrong I would be greatly appreciate it. I did check for key constraints in the Account table. It is giving the error in the account table.

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    AcctNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MemberID int,
    Balance double,
    PIN int,
    creationDate date,
    InitialBalance double,
    CreatedByEmployee int,
    type VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(AcctNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(MemberID) REFERENCES Member(MemNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(CreatedByEmployee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Member( 
    MemNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    CreditScore int, 
    AcctOpened date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11),  
    Address VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(MemNum)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee( 
    EmpId int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11), 
    HireDate date, 
    Salary double, 
    EmpLevel VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(EmpId)
);
```

Comment: The `Member` table and `Employee` table has to exist before reference. i.e., Create both of these tables before creating `Account` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the referencing table first before creating the table which is referring other tables with FOREIGN key.

The order of table creation should be as

```
CREATE TABLE Member( 
    MemNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    CreditScore int, 
    AcctOpened date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11),  
    Address VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(MemNum)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee( 
    EmpId int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11), 
    HireDate date, 
    Salary double, 
    EmpLevel VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Account(
    AcctNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MemberID int,
    Balance double,
    PIN int,
    creationDate date,
    InitialBalance double,
    CreatedByEmployee int,
    type VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(AcctNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(MemberID) REFERENCES Member(MemNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(CreatedByEmployee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the Foreign key for Member before creating the table so it does not exist yet. Change the order you are creating the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Member( 
    MemNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    CreditScore int, 
    AcctOpened date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11),  
    Address VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(MemNum)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee( 
    EmpId int AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    DOB date, 
    SSN VARCHAR(11), 
    HireDate date, 
    Salary double, 
    EmpLevel VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(EmpId)
);
CREATE TABLE Account(
    AcctNum int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MemberID int,
    Balance double,
    PIN int,
    creationDate date,
    InitialBalance double,
    CreatedByEmployee int,
    type VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(AcctNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(MemberID) REFERENCES Member(MemNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(CreatedByEmployee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong order of creating tables

try this

1- Create member table first

2- employer table second

3- account table in last

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47d58

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse the order of table creation is important here.
Create the Member and Employee tables first, followed by the Account. It should work fine.